# Panorama item - animate header position

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

There are situations were you have an "extra wide" item in a panorama (item which extends over the boundaries of the screen), but a very short title (header) for it.

See, for example, the "recent contacts" in Mango, or some sections of the new Marketplace or Xbox hub. You can see that the item title moves a little as you scroll horizontally so that (part of) it is always visible.

Anyone can enlight us on how to achieve the same effect?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are setting the Panoramas Title it will scroll because it is on top of the panorama items. Or you wanna set the panorama items title and you want it to behave the same way?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I'm talking about the item header here and not the Panorama title. There are many example of this behaviour in Mango, I don't think there were any in Nodo.

Comment: It's ok i just wanted to clear things up a little bit. Sadly i don't know the answer you are looking for but would be great to know if it is possible what you ask.

Comment: Thank you BigL, it would be indeed interesting to know if a solution exists that doesn't require TOO MUCH hassle for such a small cosmetic issue - that's what I'm after :)

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe exists only in the built in hubs. The hubs are not built with the same controls as are available to 3rd party developers.

Unfortunately the silverlight controls you describe do not support this functionality.
You could build your own, alternative, control and use that instead but it would be a LOT of work to get the same behaviour as the built in controls.
Instead, I'd recommend reviewing your design to make it clearer what the user is looking at in the panorama item so they don't need a piece of text teling them.

Comment: Thank you Matt and you're right on that: I might just use a longer text for the heading and that would do. But I'd be very much interested to see how much work (and custom code) it would take to mimic that cool behaviour.